# Multiple screen after Ubuntu 12.04 LTS updated - VMware Player

Tags: 12.04, windows-7, vmware-player

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS within VMware Player and running on Windows 7 64-bit environment.

Yesterday, I got multiple screens after update it. After that, I tried to reinstall VMware tools again. The issue still there. Would you please help me out, the scree shot is like this:

[image]

Comment: Do you have CCSM installed? If yes...change the no. of workspace to one in General options (CCSM). This i think is due to display settings mismatch. In VM and Ubuntu Display settings.

Comment: I didn't install CCSM in my Ubuntu.

Comment: If you have more than one work space then reduce it to one. Please revert if issue is resolved by this or not.

Answer (score 1):

**I think it is might because of the VMware Player is not working properly with the new update.**

Here is a possible sulution:  **Disable vmwgfx fbdev in ubuntu**.

1. BE SURE TO BACKUP YOUR VM, BE IT USING SNAPSHOTS OR A COPY
2. Edit the VM file ***/etc/modprobe.d/vmwgfx-fbdev.conf*** to set
   ***options vmwgfx enable_fbdev=0***
3. Run
   ***sudo update-initramfs -u***
4. Reboot

Then issue should be resolved.